# Category "Match products by rule" not considering store price

Tags: magento2, category-products

We are using category "Match products by rule" option for assigning products to categories. We have multiple stores with different currencies. When we save a category at the store level having currency, let's say in pounds and put a condition of price less than 50 it assigns the products correctly for that store with products having price less than 50 pounds.

But when we check the same category in different store with different currency, it changes the products with wrong prices assigned.

How to resolve this?

Comment: which is the scope of the price in your setup?